# PlayonLinux can not find curl (cURL)

Tags: installation

I made the download from Ubuntu Software-Center, but when I try to start PlayonLinux I get the answer above.
What should I do next?

I'm using Linux the first time in my life.., please don't answer in a "complicated" way^^

Thanks anyway!

p.s. english is not my native language, but i guess it will work out
     answers are also welcome in german & portuguese^^

Comment: Have you tried installing the `curl` package?

Comment: yes, I did, but it didn't work out..., or maybe I made something wrong? should I include the package into PlayonLinux?.., and if yes, how?

Comment: did you do `sudo apt-get install curl`?

Comment: like I wrote in my question: I'm using Linux about to weaks, more or less^^, sorry..., I'm not sure that I already able to avoid errors using the terminal...., is there no other/easier way?

Comment: In Software-Center search for `curl`. That should find a package named `curl`. Install it and try again to start PlayonLinux. Do you still get an error?

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try it when i'm back at my home.., i'm using my netbook while i'm travelling in the moment.., i will be back in about a half hour, more or less

Comment: danke dir Florian...,

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package named `curl`.
To install it from terminal type as

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```